# How to correctly configure Facebook Connect for PhoneGap Build version 3.3?

Tags: android, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I’m not finding any recent documentation on how to correctly install Facebook Connect on Android for PhoneGap Build version 3.3. Each time I try to authenticate a user on an android emulator nothing happens. I’m not even sure I am doing the process right. My question is, where in the process am I going wrong?

On PhoneGap’s plugins page for Facebook Connect, it states that you place the plugin XML into your config.xml. I have done so. I have already created an app on Facebook’s developer site and added the Android hash to Facebook.

Originally it seemed that you also needed to include the JavaScript SDK in index.html, but that is not activating the sign in either when I call FB.login().

I have the Facebook app installed on my emulator.
[These are the instructions that I have been following:](https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/962eb0a1c07935ff813e28aa9eaa5581f2e10416/README.md)

What is the correct way to install Facebook connect for PhoneGap Build version 3.3?

Answer (score 0):

first you must create an App in facebook  and use that `[APP_ID] = Your APP_ID as registered on Facebook` in your  and you `APP_NAME` .

Comment: I have already added that to the XML in config.xml. Is it just the way I am trying to call FB.login()? Do I include the JavaScript as shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart)?

Comment: Yes you have to use the javascript that has been provide by the Facebook. You can do the research in Facebook  API documentation.